# Why are classes of runtime dependency available at compile time?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I am working on maven-spring project in eclipse where I have declared below dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As per my understanding, classes from org.springframework.context should be available only at runtime and not at compile time. But I am able to import classes from above package in code without any compilation error (in Eclipse). This is my code:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");
}

}
```

Here, my basic question is how above code is working. It should give compile time error when I am trying to use ApplicationContext as I have included "spring-context" artifact with runtime scope? Is my eclipse doing some trick here? What am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to compile this on the command line? If it fails there, it will be to do with the way eclipse builds the build path. You could also check if it is being pulled in as a transitive compile dependency?

Comment: If a library has been downloaded to the maven repository in your machine previously, you will not get error when auto-completion in IDE. You can check your maven repository and try with another version like `3.1.1` or something that doesn't exist in your maven repo.

Comment: Thanks Ben, A Nayar. When I tried to compile from command line, this code did fail with expected error!! It's the Eclipse IDE that is not obeying pom.xml and directly compiling my code against all dependencies without considering scope.

Comment: I am still not sure as why Eclipse behaves like this or is there any way to change Eclipse's behavior in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A compile time dependency may or may not be needed at runtime. In case of **compile** scoped dependency, the jar will be copied to your classpath and hence will be used at runtime. On the other hand you can compile your code with certain dependency and at runtime you can use some other implementation of that dependency with **runtime** scope.

Comment: I guess you didn't understood the question